# Css float:right 100% Height, image align bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using a `float: right` on my [website](http://makestrange.co.uk/test/structures.html). I want to make that div 100% of the window height minus a 10px margin. I want the height to resize with the page.

I also want the image in it to sit at the bottom of the 'container' minus 10px padding.

I've tried adjusting everything, and am sure its something in the code conflicting but i just can't work it out.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) instead of floating for this, you can make elements expand by setting for example `top` and `bottom` at the same time.

Absolute positioning could work for the image as well if you set its `bottom` to `10px` (its offset parent will already be the right container, because any `position` other than the default `static` makes the element an offset parent).

Quick example:

```
/* this makes your body take up the whole screen */
html, body { height: 100%; }
/* the positioning magic */
#right { width: 100px; position: absolute;top: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 20px; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cNwNy/)

​**UPDATE**: and an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNwNy/1/) to show an example on putting another element in the container and positioning it to the bottom.

```
#image { position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 20px;  }
```

Comment: that makes alot of sense..... thanks very much. think i've just been bangin my head trying to get float to work rather than rethinking it..... muchos gracias!